# GridView column .different fonts for headertext

Tags: gridview, headertext

i have a requirement to show a gridview column as mandatory field(using asterix sign) ie

SomColumn1 SomeColumn2*

my problem is how can i make the column name and asterisk sign in two different fonts

meaning SomeColumn2 is blue color and * is Red color

Comment: how have you bound the gridview? templatefields?

Comment: yes ,it has been bound with the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have bound the GridView using TemplateField, you can set HeaderStyle on each column like this.

```
<HeaderStyle BackColor="Blue" />
```

Apply Red in the same fashion to the other column. And if you want to change the class itself, try.

```
<HeaderStyle CssClass="myclass" />
```

Comment: Thanks . actually i forgot that there exists header template :) , adding two lables and defining their font solved the issue..thnx